# Tweetinvi 5.0 Get tweet replies

Tags: c#, twitter, tweetinvi

I want to get the list of every replies of a tweet with Tweetinvi 5.0.

I found this in another post but I can't reproduce it

```
var directReplies = Tweetinvi.Search.SearchDirectRepliesTo(tweet);
var replies = Tweetinvi.Search.SearchRepliesTo(tweet, true);
```

Is there a way to do so ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The only way that I found to do it is by making a search with the @ and then filtering with InReplyToStatusId :

```
SearchTweetsParameters param = new($"@{tweet.CreatedBy.ScreenName} ");
var relies = (await Client.Search.SearchTweetsAsync(param))
                     .Where(e => e.InReplyToStatusId == tweet.Id)
                     .ToList();
```

This is "working" but not really effective